# MongoDB Node - Getting the _id of an inserted object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am having a conceptual problem with MongoDB, having recently switched from a relational database.

I am trying to store an image with something like:

```
    exports.save = function ( input, image, callback) {
    console.log('Image Provider, trying to handle image ...');
    input.date = new Date();
    if (input._id) {
        input._id = new ObjectID(input._id);
    }
    console.log("image is " + image + " image size is " + image.size);
    if (image && image.size) {
        var data = fs.readFileSync(image.path);
        input.image = new MongoDb.Binary(data);
        input.imageType = image.headers['content-type'];
        input.imageName = image.name;
    console.log("input is " + input);
    }

    db.collection("images", function (error, collection) {
        collection.save(input, {safe: true}, callback);
    });
};
```

This is called as follows:

```
ImageProvider.save(input, function(err, objects) {

    input.image_id = objects._id;
    console.log('[inside] objects id is ' + input.image_id);
    if (err) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
});
```

I want to use the image _id in another collection, basically it inserts a reference to this image object in the image collection . Due to the async call, when I insert the next object into the other collection, the _id is not yet available.

Is there a standard pattern for inserting a reference to another collection object OR is the 
best method simply to insert the whole (other object) in the same collection ?

## UPDATE:

I found a solution / strategy which is basically to create the ObjectID before calling the SAVE funcion

something like :

```
 ObjectID = MongoDb.ObjectID;
 input._id = new ObjectID();
```

Then save the input. In this case the _id will always be valid no matter how long it takes for the async call to return.

Comment: Side note: the `fs.readFileSync` call will block your program until it has entirely read the file from disk. You'd better use the asynchronous `fs.readFile` call, which will allow Node to do something useful while waiting for the file to be read from disk.

Comment: Do a `console.log(objects)` -- it may be an array containing your object.

Comment: Thanks for the hints : it seems as if one strategy is to manually create the ObjectID, then do the insert. The ObjectID will be valid no matter what `ObjectID = MongoDb.ObjectID`; and `input._id = new` ObjectID();

Comment: the callback of `save` and `insert` returns an array. If you change to `input.image_id = objects[0]._id` it could work. But _id is of type `ObjectID`, but has a nice toString method :-)

Comment: Thanks all, the main issue was the async nature of the call, pre-setting the object id solves two issues (1) Timing does not matter (2) easy access to the objecID outside the callback (i.e scope issues)

Answer (score 0):

I see you have found a solution, which is to specify an `_id` before saving using the MongoDb driver's `ObjectID()` function. However, here are a couple other options since the driver does not currently support returning the object or `_id` after inserting...

You could immediately query the database for the for your `input` object, since it's guaranteed to match, like so:

```
collection.find(input, function (err, savedImage) {
  // use savedImage._id here...
}
```

The downside to this is that it may be possible that query could match more than one document (depending on the data your are inserting). If that's the case, you could always sort on a timestamp and limit to 1 document (hint: there's actually a timestamp embedded in all ObjectIds).

Another solution that you hinted at in your question is using embedding rather than references in multiple collections. This is probably a better solution, and follows the philosophy of schema-less design better. Embedding will probably also be faster. But it may be harder to re-design your application to make this work.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I see the advantage of 'embedding' although gets messy for binary data. Secondly I would like to access the binary data in other 'contexts'. I found setting the ObjectID to be a very effective solution (especially since with callbacks etc, it is difficult to reliably get the _id back (in time)).

Comment: Absolutely. I just wanted to add your solution, plus these other two in the same answer to be semantically correct in case others come across this question with their own projects.

Comment: understood, in theory you could query the input object (as you suggest) before it is actually inserted (especially is a large amount of binary data is inserted) ... might be worth putting that edit in